# Stop a variable from updating further if another variable hits 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some variables that are updated on scroll in jQuery.

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var width = site.logoWidth - scrollTop;
var logoPadding = scrollTop;
```

I want to stop the `logoPadding` variable from updating when the `width` variable hits 0 and then continue if the `width` goes above 0 again. I have currently got this but I am not sure how to stop the `logoPadding` variable from changing.

```
if (width < 0) {
   var width = 0;
   var logoPadding = ;
}
```

Full Code

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var windowHeight = $(window).height();
   var logoWidth = $('#main-logo').width();
   var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   var width = site.logoWidth - scrollTop;
   var logoPadding = scrollTop;

   if (width < 0) {
      var width = 0;
      var logoPadding = ;
   }

   if (scrollTop < site.windowHeight + 10) {
      $('#main-logo').css({
         'width' : width,
         'padding-bottom' : logoPadding
      })
   }
});
```

Comment: Maybe not the real problem, but the var logoPadding line is wrong (it misses a value)

var logoPadding = 0; 
return;

maybe?

Comment: you don't want `logoPadding = 0` isn't it ? 
you just want to keep its last value ?

Comment: @Tarekas Yes thats correct. So it could be any number. I want it to stop on whatever value it has when the width hits 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (width < 0) {
  var width = 0;
  var logoPadding = ;
}
```

should be

```
if (width <= 0) {
  width = 0;
  logoPadding = 0;
  return;
}
```

probably

Answer (score 0):

First declare & initialize logoPadding before scroll function.

`var logoPadding=0`

Then :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var windowHeight = $(window).height();
   var logoWidth = $('#main-logo').width();
   var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   var width = site.logoWidth - scrollTop;

   if (width < 0) {
      var width = 0;
       //if width is zero, don't update logoPadding
    }

else{
logoPadding = scrollTop; //update logoPadding
}
   if (scrollTop < site.windowHeight + 10) {
      $('#main-logo').css({
         'width' : width,
         'padding-bottom' : logoPadding
      })
   }
});
```